# Get extract of Sybase data as INSERT statements, with order considering table dependencies

Tags: sql, sybase, database-administration, sap-ase

I want to create a SQL script to populate a DEV database using INSERT statements. (Preferably using INSERT statements, rather than binary form, so that I can safely check-in the script to version control).

I can easily extract the INSERT statements using various tools.  But I haven't found a way to extract the INSERT statements *in an order so that when run, FK constraints will not be violated.*

I've used SQL Server tools which accomplish this.  e.g. RedGate.  But cannot seem to find a Sybase compatible method.

I am using Sybase ASE

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here at Redgate we don't often get Sybase requests and there are few vendors who produce tools for this market. You could try [DBBest](https://www.dbbest.com/products/database-compare-suite/), who specialize in breadth of RDBMS support.

Comment: Gee thanks.  Looks like it's worth looking into.  Unfortunately I'll probably have to remove this question (as requests for tool recommendations are not allowed).  But thanks for responding.

Comment: Or just edit your question and ask for a _way_ of generating insert statements. The answer could be a code snippet or a tool...